# Ampersand(&) (very command execute) with QProcess

Tags: c++, linux, qt, external, qprocess

I'm using Qt and tcsh over it, need to execute something like:

```
tcsh: pwd & ls
```

in Qt:

```
QString cmd = "pwd & ls";
QProcess *process = new QProcess;
process->start(cmd);
process->waitForBytesWritten();
process->waitForFinished();
qDebug() << process->readAll();`
```

The problem is in ampersand ("&"), and process returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's figure out what happens when you execute a single command, like `pwd`. When you do it, the shell process [forks](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) (i.e. produces a child process), then the child process [turns into](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) `pwd` process and acquires control over the terminal.

Next, if you execute `pwd &`, all the same happens, but the child process (`pwd` in our example) does not get control over the terminal. It runs as a *background* process, while the shell continues to work with the terminal. For example, you may run a GUI program (`firefox &`), and the shell will be ready to run the next one immediately.

Finally, when you execute `pwd & ls`, all the same as in the previous case happens, but the shell forks one more time and runs `ls` in foreground. As you might guess, `pwd & ls &` yields both processes being run in background, and you may execute as many commands as you want at once.

Now let's get back to Qt. `QProcess` does not run any shell before running the command. Thus, when you run `pwd & ls` via `QProcess`, `pwd` will be the only program executed, but it [will get](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start-1) two command line arguments: `&` and `ls`. Both of them will be ignored.

So the equivalent of `pwd & ls` will be *two* `QProcess` objects, each running a single command.

Another solution is to run the shell explicitly to make the arguments being parsed:

```
QString cmd = "tcsh -c \"pwd & ls\"";
QProcess *process = new QProcess;
process->start(cmd);
process->waitForBytesWritten();
process->waitForFinished();
qDebug() << process->readAll();
```

Comment: @elifmutlu I tested the code and found how to pass arguments to the shell. Use escaped doublequetes instead of apostrophes. See the edited answer.